# Joomla white screen - Class '\Joomla\CMS\Input\Input' not found

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

We encounter some problems with a 'new' Joomla! website. A customer has moved there website to our server with the error below. This error was also present on previous server.

We also can't get into administrator section.

```
Warning: Class '\Joomla\CMS\Input\Input' not found in httpdocs/libraries/loader.php on line 663 

Error: Failed to start application: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Input\Input' not found
```

Comment: Which version of Joomla? Did you do a clean install of Joomla before the migration? If all you did was copy the folders/files from the previous installation, then of course you'll get the same error. Sounds like you are missing some parts of the Joomla core

Comment: @SloanThrasher I did not say that I was expecting a different result on the new server. Is it possible to reinstall / rebuild the joomla core files, without losing data?

Comment: What version of PHP is the new server using?

Comment: @Lodder PHP 7.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the core files with new core files from a fresh Joomla! installation and the error is gone.